# Show loading swf while view is loading in Flex

Tags: flash, flex4, preloader, flex-spark

In my mobile flex application I have a view which quite big. I am showing a swf using swfloader in creation complete method of the view, but the swf freezes until the view is loaded, so it was not usable. Is there any way that the swf excutes while the view is loading smoothly..

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should load and exectue heavy methods in the background. If I remember correctly you may put it in a queue or something else. But there is no on-board mechanism as far as I remember..